# laravel not saving model attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a controller that should update an `amount` attribute and save it to a db. I can verify via `getAmount` that the model has the correct amount, but its not being saved to the database and no error is returned. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my controller:

```
    $response = Input::json()->all();
    $ticket = Ticket::find($id);
    $ticket->setAmount($response['amount']);
    $ticket->getAmount(); //for debugging
    $ticket->save();
    return $ticket;
```

And my Ticket Model:

```
class Ticket extends \Eloquent {    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $amount = 0;

    function setAmount($amount){
        $this->amount = $amount*100000000;
    }

    function getAmount(){
        return $this->amount/100000000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$amount` property from your `Ticket` class and it'll work.

---

BTW, you can also make this work with Eloquent's mutators:

```php
class Ticket extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function setAmountAttribute($amount)
    {
        $this->attributes['amount'] = $amount * 100000000;
    }
}
```

Then set it in your controller as you would any other property:

```php
$ticket = Ticket::find($id);
$ticket->amount = $response['amount'];
$ticket->save();
```

and Eloquent will automatically call your setter function for you.

Comment: That did it, thanks! What exactly was the problem here?

Comment: @AakilFernandes - Eloquent uses its own internal `$attributes` property to track the column values. When you try to set/get a non-existent property on your class, Eloquent will automatically resolve it to that internal `$attributes` array. Since you have set your own `$amount` property, *that* was being set instead of the `amount` index on the `$attributes` array.